# JBoss Deployment Error - Failed Services

Tags: java, eclipse, server, wildfly

Trying to debug my application in Wildfly 8.x server, I confront that error:

```
16:03:18,740 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.3.3.Final
16:03:19,098 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.2.Final
16:03:19,170 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015899: WildFly 8.2.1.Final "Tweek" starting
16:03:20,560 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015014: Re-attempting failed deployment paco.war
16:03:20,633 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found paco.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called paco.war.dodeploy
16:03:20,651 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
16:03:20,671 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-3) XNIO version 3.3.0.Final
16:03:20,680 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-3) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.3.0.Final
16:03:20,730 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 8 core threads with 64 task threads based on your 4 available processors
16:03:20,738 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 32) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
16:03:20,746 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 45) JBAS013171: Activating Security Subsystem
16:03:20,748 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 40) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
16:03:20,762 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
16:03:20,779 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.logging] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (IronJacamar 1.1.9.Final)
16:03:20,788 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS013170: Current PicketBox version=4.0.21.Final
16:03:20,802 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
16:03:20,809 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS010417: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
16:03:20,812 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS017502: Undertow 1.1.8.Final starting
16:03:20,817 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 47) JBAS017502: Undertow 1.1.8.Final starting
16:03:20,827 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
16:03:20,831 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
16:03:20,868 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) JBAS010153: Node identifier property is set to the default value. Please make sure it is unique.
16:03:20,874 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) JBAS012615: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
16:03:20,876 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBoss Remoting version 4.0.7.Final
16:03:20,991 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 47) JBAS017527: Creating file handler for path C:\Wild\wildfly-8.2.1.Final/welcome-content
16:03:21,088 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS017525: Started server default-server.
16:03:21,095 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS017531: Host default-host starting
16:03:21,361 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\Wild\wildfly-8.2.1.Final\standalone\deployments
16:03:21,366 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "paco.war" (runtime-name: "paco.war")
16:03:21,504 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS017519: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
16:03:21,698 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
16:03:22,038 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBWS022052: Starting JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.3.2.Final
16:03:23,905 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015960: Class Path entry vaadin-server-7.3.5.jar in /C:/Wild/wildfly-8.2.1.Final/standalone/deployments/paco.war/WEB-INF/lib/confirmdialog-2.1.2.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:03:23,905 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015960: Class Path entry vaadin-sass-compiler-0.9.10.jar in /C:/Wild/wildfly-8.2.1.Final/standalone/deployments/paco.war/WEB-INF/lib/confirmdialog-2.1.2.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:03:23,906 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015960: Class Path entry vaadin-shared-7.3.5.jar in /C:/Wild/wildfly-8.2.1.Final/standalone/deployments/paco.war/WEB-INF/lib/confirmdialog-2.1.2.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:03:23,906 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015960: Class Path entry json-0.0.20080701.jar in /C:/Wild/wildfly-8.2.1.Final/standalone/deployments/paco.war/WEB-INF/lib/confirmdialog-2.1.2.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:03:23,907 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015960: Class Path entry jsoup-1.6.3.jar in /C:/Wild/wildfly-8.2.1.Final/standalone/deployments/paco.war/WEB-INF/lib/confirmdialog-2.1.2.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:03:23,908 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015960: Class Path entry vaadin-server-7.5.0.jar in /C:/Wild/wildfly-8.2.1.Final/standalone/deployments/paco.war/WEB-INF/lib/confirmdialog-2.1.3.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:03:23,908 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015960: Class Path entry vaadin-shared-7.5.0.jar in /C:/Wild/wildfly-8.2.1.Final/standalone/deployments/paco.war/WEB-INF/lib/confirmdialog-2.1.3.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:03:24,645 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver (version 12.1)
16:03:24,674 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS010417: Started Driver service with driver-name = paco.war_oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver_12_1
16:03:24,800 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (MSC service thread 1-4) Initializing AtmosphereFramework
16:03:24,808 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (MSC service thread 1-4) Initializing AtmosphereFramework
16:03:24,825 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./paco: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./paco: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.vaadin.server.communication.PushRequestHandler.initAtmosphere(Ljavax/servlet/ServletConfig;)Lorg/atmosphere/cpr/AtmosphereFramework;
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.JSR356WebsocketInitializer.initAtmosphereForVaadinServlet(JSR356WebsocketInitializer.java:152)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.JSR356WebsocketInitializer.contextInitialized(JSR356WebsocketInitializer.java:118)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:173)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:194)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:87)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.start(UndertowDeploymentService.java:72)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    ... 3 more

16:03:24,831 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "paco.war")]) - failure description: {
    "JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./paco" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./paco: Failed to start service
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.vaadin.server.communication.PushRequestHandler.initAtmosphere(Ljavax/servlet/ServletConfig;)Lorg/atmosphere/cpr/AtmosphereFramework;"},
    "JBAS014879: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
        "Services that were unable to start:" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"paco.war\".deploymentCompleteService"],
        "Services that may be the cause:" => ["jboss.jdbc-driver.hsqldb_jar"]
    }
}
16:03:24,833 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("data-source" => "DefaultDS")
]) - failure description: {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
    "jboss.data-source.java:/DefaultDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.hsqldb_jar]",
    "jboss.driver-demander.java:/DefaultDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.hsqldb_jar]"
]}
16:03:24,835 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("data-source" => "DefaultDS")
]) - failure description: {
    "JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.data-source.java:/DefaultDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.hsqldb_jar]",
        "jboss.driver-demander.java:/DefaultDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.hsqldb_jar]"
    ],
    "JBAS014879: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
        "Services that were unable to start:" => [
            "jboss.data-source.reference-factory.DefaultDS",
            "jboss.naming.context.java.DefaultDS"
        ],
        "Services that may be the cause:" => ["jboss.jdbc-driver.hsqldb_jar"]
    }
}
16:03:24,914 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS018559: Deployed "paco.war" (runtime-name : "paco.war")
16:03:24,918 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.jdbc-driver.hsqldb_jar (missing) dependents: [service jboss.driver-demander.java:/DefaultDS, service jboss.data-source.java:/DefaultDS] 
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./paco: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./paco: Failed to start service

16:03:25,061 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
16:03:25,061 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
16:03:25,062 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: WildFly 8.2.1.Final "Tweek" started (with errors) in 6644ms - Started 264 of 326 services (6 services failed or missing dependencies, 92 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
16:03:25,175 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS010418: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = paco.war_oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver_12_1
16:03:25,211 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-6) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.1.3.Final
16:03:25,665 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment paco.war (runtime-name: paco.war) in 498ms
16:03:25,859 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018558: Undeployed "paco.war" (runtime-name: "paco.war")
16:03:25,861 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.deployment.unit."paco.war".component."com.patientconsent.PatientconsentUI$Servlet".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."paco.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."paco.war".component."com.patientconsent.views.TableCheckBoxUI$Servlet".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."paco.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."paco.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."paco.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."paco.war".component."com.vaadin.server.communication.JSR356WebsocketInitializer".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."paco.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."paco.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."paco.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."paco.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."paco.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."paco.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."paco.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."paco.war".component."org.atmosphere.container.Servlet30CometSupport$CometListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."paco.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./paco (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."paco.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./paco

16:03:29,961 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015003: Found paco.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called paco.war.dodeploy
```

Environment:

- Java 1.7
- Eclipse Luna
- Wildfly 8.x

I have already searched each one of the errors and nothing really helped me. Can you please give me your lights about what could possibly be the fault? Please inform me if you want another information about my app's enviroment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like database connection issue. Please check

1. If database is up for accepting connections.
2. Any firewall, stopping opening of ports etc.
3. Do check jta="true" or false is allowed and code written.
4. Check if you have packaged associated jdbc driver jar file with application.

But yes, answer to your query is; this error is related to database configuration. Please check appropriate documentation.

Comment: Thank you. I also thought about the jar file, and I will check it!